# Row level Data authorization in .net core

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

Could someone please help me to implement data authorization in .net core, ef core.

Our requirement is to give users data authorization permissions at database table row level. When searching / accessing data only authorized vehicles should be seen. Performance is key.

**What is the best way to create authorization relations between the users (hundreds) and the data (millions)**

For example we have vehicles (this table can be in millions with other columns)

| **VehicleId** | **Make** | **Model** | **Color** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Audi | A1 | White |
| 2 | Audi | A1 | Blue |
| 3 | Audi | A1 | Orange |
| 4 | Audi | A2 | White |
| 5 | Audi | A2 | Blue |
| 6 | Audi | A2 | Orange |

Example data authorization requirements

- User1 - VehicleId 5, 6
- User2 - A1 model
- User3 - A2 model
- User4 - Audi Make
- User5 - Different makes or models or colors etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just add an input for the authorized cars and update it when you need.
Or group the Authorized cars by and Identification.